# How do I add a new row to a DataSet?

Tags: c#

Using Visual Express 2010 I've added a DataGridView and have bound it to a database table. I need to add a row to this table but how?

I've got the following

fuelStopsTableAdapter

fuelStopsDataSet1 (this consists of the columns date, cost, car-string)

I believe I have to create a DataRow from my DataSet then add that to the DataSet? Then update the table using the DataSet?

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `DataRow` object by the [DataTable.NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) method by the dataset and assign values to `DataRow` columns and add to `DataTable`.

```
DataRow dr = dataset.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr["ColumnName1"] = "Some Value 1";
dr["ColumnName2"] = "Some Value 2";
dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
```

*DataTable.NewRow*

> You must use the NewRow method to create new DataRow objects with the
>   same schema as the DataTable. After creating a DataRow, you can add it
>   to the DataRowCollection, through the DataTable object's Rows
>   property. When you use NewRow to create new rows, the rows must be
>   added to or deleted from the data table before you call Clear, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx).